# Bower not installing locally but to my appdata folder on Windows

Tags: bower

I have this bower.json:

```
{
  "name": "project",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "requirejs": "2.1.17",
  }
}
```

When running `bower install bower.json` it installs it somewhere else. How do I get it to install in current folder `bower_components`?

I tried to install just the one from command line too but it's not installed locally.

```
bower install requirejs#2.1.17
```

Answer (score 0):

For anyone having the same issue please note that it should always be `bower install`.

To run the local bower.json add config:

```
bower install --config.directory=mylocalfolder --config.cwd=drive:/..../folder
```

Available configs are described at [Bower configuration](https://github.com/bower/spec/blob/master/config.md)